# Trying to change ASP .NET Label from code behind: The name "idLabel" does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET project using C#. When I try to change a label (which is created in .aspx file) from the my code behind file (aspx.cs), the label does not get recognized in my code behind file.

I tried `idLabel.Text = "example";` but an error pops up saying:

> The name 'idLabel' does not exist in the current context.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Post the aspx markup for the label.

Comment: check this one code file vs code behind https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/difference-between-codebehind-and-code-file

Answer (score 0):

We need more information.

if you just drop a asp.net label on the page, then your code should work.

however, if the label is inside of a gridview, repeater, listview etc? Then you have MANY rows, and thus a different approach is required on how to reference a given label, since if in a gridview or listview, then you have "many" rows, and thus which instance of the label (what row) are you trying to refer to?

This is why additional information is required here.

If you have this markup on the page, say like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="idLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Then, yes your code should work.

however, if nested in a repeating type of control, then you will have "many" rows of data, and thus a different approach is required.